# Is it possible to do purification of Sodium Sulphate and which companies do this?

Tags: chemical-engineering, chemistry

If Sinter filter generates lots of Sodium Sulphate and then is there a way to make purification of this and which companies are already do this process?

Comment: Have you just got a job in a blast furnace?

Comment: As I said in a comment to your previous version of this question, the market price for Sodium Sulphate is less than 100USD per ton, so you are unlikely to make any money from extracting it from a filter and purifying it unless you have *huge* quantities of it.

Comment: @alephzero price is not important, we just need to recover or sell these sodium sulphate even with a 1 usd, the main problem is the area of waste sodium sulphate getting bigger and bigger and we need to get away with it somehow.